# Every monomorphism is an equalizer

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

I have read that in the category of groups every monomorphism is an equalizer. The proof I found uses the notion of amalgamation, which I don't know, and refers to a book on group theory by Kuros which I don't have... Can you please explain me why in the category of groups every mono is an equalizer? I will accept both an answer using amalgamation and answers using other (possibly easier) methods

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. In the category of groups every kernel is a mono, but there are monos which are not kernels.

Edit: The question is changed. Any equalizer in a category is monic, but the converse need not be true in general. It is true however for the category of groups; all monos in this category are regular: see [here](http://math.andrej.com/2010/11/10/subgroups-are-equalizers-constructively/).

Literature: Mitchell: Theory of Categories; it contains a proof that every monomorphism is an equalizer in Grps, due to Eilenberg-Moore.

Comment: So what Borceux says in Handbook of categorical algebra is false!?!?!?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I am gonna editing the question

Comment: @bateman, in the category of groups, normal subgroups are precisely kernels of morphisms. Thus, counterexample to "every mono is a kernel" is a subgroup that is not normal. If you switch to abelian groups, then all monos are normal (as claimed in Borceux's Handbook) simply because all subgroups of abelian group are normal.

Comment: @Ennar Yes thank you. Now I have edited my question, since in the original form it was simply wrong